# When the Matlab function image displays a matrix with more elements than pixels on a screen how does it decide which matrix elements to display?

Tags: image, matlab, downsampling

I am trying to look for trends in a large data matrix, say 50,000 x 1000 elements. If I use the [`image`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) command the matrix is printed to the screen. I would like to know how Matlab's `image` function decides which elements of the matrix to display considering there are not enough pixels on my screen to display so many elements? In other words, which downsampling algorithm is it applying to the matrix?

Comment: You are using `imshow()` I presume?

Comment: `nearest`-interpolation (as described in the `interp2` function) is used. For alternatives check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342693/how-to-avoid-image-display-artifacts-in-matlab

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know if print will print the interpolated or the raw image?

Comment: Don't know. I would export at full resolution using `imsave`.

Answer (score 0):

Nearest interpolation (as described in the `interp2` function) is used. For alternatives check this question:  [How to avoid image display artifacts in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342693/how-to-avoid-image-display-artifacts-in-matlab)